# Improving Co-Authors Plus Plugin

Tags: author, quick-edit, terms

I've been using the Co-Authors Plus plugin for assigning multiple authors to posts. The authors are very particular in the ordering of the names on the public-facing side of the website so I need the ability to arbitrarily order the authors.

It turns out it's not that hard using a line of jQuery to make the Co-Author Plus metabox sortable on the edit post screen:

```
jQuery('#coauthors-edit').ready(function($) {
    $( "#coauthors-list" ).sortable({ axis: 'y', containment: 'parent'     });
});
```

Now I can drag and drop to re-order the authors and it all works! Yay!

The problem is the order of the authors rearranges if the post is modified in quick edit/batch edit mode on the post listing screen (the page that lists all of the posts before you choose one to go in and edit).

I need to find a way to prevent the author terms from updating during a quick edit/batch edit post and for the life of me can't figure out how it is done.

Maybe someone here can help shed some light on what I'm missing. The source code is here: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/co-authors-plus/trunk/co-authors-plus.php

Any ideas?

Comment: Closing since the question was taken to the support forums instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to take this question in the [WordPress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/tags/co-authors-plus) :)

Comment: Done. Thank you very much! http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-co-authors-plus-making-authors-sortable?replies=1#post-2497699